# PHP 7. Сравниваем данные

Tags: php, php7

Уже неделя, как учу PHP.
Тут такое дело, надо сравнить данные, которые ввел пользователь.

```
<?php

// Ссылка на главную страницу.
$src = '<br><a href="address_book.html">Перейти на главную страницу.</a>';

$david = [
    'name'    => 'David',
    'surname' => 'KA',
    'age'     => '18',
    'city'    => 'Almaty',
];

// Если такой человек существует.
if (isset($_POST['people']) == 'Brendon') {
    echo $david['surname'];
    echo $src;
}

// Если не существует.
else {
    echo "Человек с именем {$_POST['people']} в Базе не существует.";
    echo $src;
}
```

?>

Каким бы имя не было, всё равно выводится, в данном случае фамилия человека. Я попробовал поставить `!=`, но будут все данные неправильные. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не people, a person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if (isset($_POST['people']) == 'Brendon') {

аналогично: `if ( true == true)`

Почитайте про [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)

В Вашем случае, надо добавить условие, поскольку `isset($_POST['people'])` и так является полноценным.

```
if (isset($_POST['people']) && $_POST['people'] == 'Brendon') {
```

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю.

Comment: @Kirill не совсем согласен с вашим исправлением.. Там всё верно было, просто надо было дописать что в сравнении с [таблицей сравнения типов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php) строка будет не строго равной true